# Why to pass a View as a function parameter, when we don't use it?

Tags: android, android-layout

Like in the code Below i have pass View v as a parameter in onCLick. But why we didn't use v in the function like we usually do with other programming?

```
btn_0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (textField.getText() .toString().matches("" ) ){
                textField.setText("");
            }

            else{

                textField.setText(textField.getText()+"0");
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: You didn't pass anything to the `onClick`. The `v` is the view that you add `onClickListener` listener. They just return the clicked view in case you need to use it, otherwise just skip it.

Comment: Adding a `new View.OnClickListener() {...}` for each clickable view may be convenient but sometimes you might want to write just one centralized `OnClickListener` for several views and then you'll need to identify the view.

Answer (score 0):

View v represents your button view

If you want to access the button , suppose you want to get the text on It. How do you get it without getting button by using findViewbyId? you will get your button like this

```
Button b=(Button)v;
```

To get the text

```
String text=b.getText();
```

In general, if you want to access the button you need to get that object. But here you'll get that from the view. Without using findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

View V is actually a view associated with it. This is not a parameter to use in the function but a view on which we are going to do the operation. For more info see this link: - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html.

It will not work if you don't pass the View as a paramter.